# What's the difference between SparkSession.catalog and SparkSession.sessionState.catalog?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning Spark, got confused about Spark's Catalog.

I found a catalog in SparkSession, which is an instance of CatalogImpl, as below

```
  /**
   * Interface through which the user may create, drop, alter or query underlying
   * databases, tables, functions etc.
   *
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  @transient lazy val catalog: Catalog = new CatalogImpl(self)
```

And I found that there is a catalog in SparkSession.sessionSate, which is an instance of SessionCatalog.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between them?

**tl;dr** None.

---

The [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/CatalogImpl.scala#L41) in `CatalogImpl` is the missing piece in your understanding:

```
private def sessionCatalog: SessionCatalog = sparkSession.sessionState.catalog
```

In other words, `SparkSession.catalog` [creates](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L607) a `CatalogImpl` that uses `sparkSession.sessionState.catalog` under the covers.

Comment: I found that SparkSession.catalog and SparkSession.sessionState.catalog have been referenced in many places simultaneously. Why Spark create two different catalog variable with the same content?

Comment: My understanding is that it's mostly developer API so some leftovers from different refactorings may have been left for later cleanup. I'm sure that the commit log for one or the other should reveal the reason(s).